# How to include qarray to QTCreator project

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I have problems with including QArray module to my qt project. I include it like this:

`#include < QArray >`

and IDE send me response: file or catalog couldn't be found (I translate it for myself - because I have other language compiler - so in english compiler resulting info might be slightly different).

I know that this might be connected with not adding proper value to .pro file, but I cannot find anywhere what should I add in it. (Like QT += core).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of Qt are you using?

There is no `QArray` in recent Qt versions. Use `QVector` instead.

QArray is deprecated migrating from Qt2 to Qt3. And changed to QMemArray.
Also, QMemArray is deprecated from Qt3 to Qt4. Read [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/porting4-overview.html#memory-arrays-qmemarray) :

> In Qt 3, the QMemArray class is used as a simple array container for
>   simple data types. This class is deprecated in Qt 4 in favor of the
>   QVector...

Comment: I am using QT4. Ok I understand now why I couldn't add it :) Thanks